# How to link parent and child ids?

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following table

```
PNLParentId  id         operator 

12           13         *
12           14         *
12           15         *

20           1          -
20           2          -

13           21         /
13           20         /
```

I have created a `foreach` loop where i get the rows and add to dataset.Then another dataset for ones that are children...but am lost of how to link them now ??

```
String dbConnection = "Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
String myCommand = "SELECT PNLParentId , Operator FROM [test].[dbo].[DimPNL] GROUP BY PNLParentId,Operator";

DataSet ds = GetDataSet(myCommand, dbConnection);
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(myCommand, connection))
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(ds1, "test");
        dt = ds1.Tables["test"];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT PNLId FROM [test].[dbo].[DimPNL]  WHERE @PNLParentId =PNLParentId and @Operator=Operator" , connection))
            {
                command1.Parameters.Add(
                    new SqlParameter(
                        "@PNLParentId", dr["PNLParentId"].ToString()));

                command1.Parameters.Add(
                    new SqlParameter(
                        "@Operator", dr["Operator"].ToString()));

                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command1);
                da1.Fill(ds2, "test1");
                dt1 = ds2.Tables["test1"];

                foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt1.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dr1["PNLId"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What kind of link are you looking for? I don't actually see any code that's adding items to a list. Could you include that code also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem is usually best done at object level. I.E. suppose you've got object

```
class Node {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int? ParentId { get; set; }
  public string Operator { get; set; }
  public Node Parent { get; set; }
  public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }
  public Node() {
    Children = new List<Node>();
  }
}
```

Then you'll do two iterations - one for loading data, one for assigning parent/child hierarchy.

```
  // dt1 is something with all rows with columns Id, ParentId, Operator together
  DataTable dt1 = null;

  var map = new Dictionary<int, Node>();
  var rootNodes = new List<Node>();
  foreach(DataRow row in dt1.Rows) {
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]);
    int? parentId = null;
    if (!row.IsNull("ParentId")) {
      parentId = Convert.ToInt32(row["ParentId"]);
    }
    string op = Convert.ToString(row["Operator"]);
    map[id] = new Node {
      Id = id,
      ParentId = parentId,
      Operator = op
    };
  }
  foreach (var pair in map) {
    if (pair.Value.ParentId.HasValue) {
      var parent = map[pair.Value.ParentId.Value];
      pair.Value.Parent = parent;
      parent.Children.Add(pair.Value);
    } else {
      rootNodes.Add(pair.Value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I will not use two datasets ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to read the last inserted identity value. Just read that after each of your parent inserts and use those when you're inserting the children.

However, I don't see you inserting anything in your code, so it might be that this isn't what you're looking for. If you're only interested in reading the ready data, well...

There's no automatic solution using just `SqlCommand` etc. The simple way would be to use e.g. a dictionary to hold the parent items, and add children to those based on their parent ID.

Or you could simply switch to e.g. EntityFramework, and let it do the work for you :)