# Child in recursive data table

Tags: c#

I have the following table

```
PNLParentId  id         operator 

12           13         *
12           14         *
12           15         *

12           1          -
12           2          -

13           21         /
13           20         /
```

I want to get the tree of ids for each different operator
How can I change the following code ? I am working on it for hours , any help would be the most appreciated .

```
var q=  from p in TypedDataTable
      where p.ParentID == null  // well get all parents
     select new 
      {
           ParentID = p.ParentID,
            child =  from c in TypedDataTable 
                      where c.ParentID == p.ID select
                           new  {ChildID=c.ID,
                         ParentID = c.ParentID}
      };
```

Comment: What do you need as the result?

Comment: @SWeko I am looking to get for the same parentid and oprator, all childs for further treatment

Comment: [How to link parent and child ids?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060828/how-to-link-parent-and-child-ids)... is it same question ??

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a class for storing the data (which you may already have auto-generated if you used something like LINQ to SQL):

```
class TypedItem
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public int ParentID {get;set;}
   public List<TypedItem> Children {get;set;}

   public TypedItem()
   {
       Children = new List<TypedItem>();
   }
}
```

Then create a recursive function to populate the data:

```
List<TypedItem> GetItems(int? parentId)
{
    var results = from p in TypedDataTable
                  where p.ParentID == parentId
                  select new TypedItem(){
                      ID = p.ID,
                      ParentID = p.ParentID
                  };

    foreach(var result in results)
    {
        result.Children = GetItems(result.ID);
    }

    return results.ToList();
}
```

Which you would call from other code like so:

```
var items = GetItems(null);
```

NOTE: It isn't clear what `TypedDataTable` is or where it is defined. I have assumed it is globally available, if it isn't then you will want to pass it as a parameter to the `GetItems` function.